# Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found

Tags: linux, ssh

I have installed OpenSSH-server, but it cannot be started. I have used both the options ssh and sshd but no result. What can be done?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeaMs.png

Comment: Are you sure you installed anything? All I see is a bunch of errors...

Comment: What else except the command "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" can be executed to install?

Comment: You should be looking into why ee.archive.ubuntu.com is not resolving and whether it should. Your problem you cannot install things, because you cannot resolve the address of the repository.